# Como reemplazar make_one_shot_iterator() del Curso intensivo de aprendizaje automático de google

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Estoy siguiendo el Curso intensivo de aprendizaje automático de google. Pero al ser algo antiguo usa la version1.x de TensorFlow, asi que pensaba cambiar los ejercicios para poder ejecutarlos en TensorFlow 2.0. Pero estoy atascado en ese ejercicio:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/first_steps_with_tensor_flow.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=firststeps-colab&hl=es#scrollTo=7UwqGbbxP53O

En concreto el codigo:

```
def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
    """Trains a linear regression model of one feature.

    Args:
      features: pandas DataFrame of features
      targets: pandas DataFrame of targets
      batch_size: Size of batches to be passed to the model
      shuffle: True or False. Whether to shuffle the data.
      num_epochs: Number of epochs for which data should be repeated. None = repeat indefinitely
    Returns:
      Tuple of (features, labels) for next data batch
    """

    # Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
    features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}                                           

    # Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating.
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,targets)) # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    # Shuffle the data, if specified.
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

    # Return the next batch of data.
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels
```

He reemplazado la linea `features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()`

por `features, labels = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(ds).get_next()`

y parece funcionar pero despues la linea:

```
_ = linear_regressor.train(
    input_fn = lambda:my_input_fn(my_feature, targets),
    steps=100
)
```

que se usa para entrenar el modelo, provoca que se cuelgue python

Tambien he intentado algo como:

```
    features, labels = ds.__iter__()
    next(ds.__iter__())
    return features, labels
```

pero devuelve el error `__iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled.`

Soy bastante inexperto en python y sigo el curso como aficionado.
¿Alguna idea sobre como solventarlo?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de varias pruebas,el cuelgue de python era un problema local.
Para reemplazar `features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()` he probado varias cosas:

```
features, labels = ds.__iter__().get_next()

iterator = ds.__iter__()
features, labels = iterator.get_next()

it = iter(ds)
features, labels = next(it)
```

Los tres casos devuelven `__iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled.` asi que probe:

```
features, labels = ds
return ds
```

Y tambien solo

```
return features, labels
```

Y ambas devuelve el mismo error, por ultimo probe:

```
return ds
```

Y misteriosamente funciono, no tengo idea de porque motivo, pero lo hizo.